# How can I browse the contents of a Berkeley DB file?

Tags: database, files, berkeleydb

I'd like to see what's in a bdb file in my Thunderbird profile:

```
$ file key3.db
key3.db: Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native byte-order)
```

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452064/how-to-view-berkeley-db-contents) and it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ db_dump -l key3.db 
db_dump: key3.db: unexpected file type or format
db_dump: open: key3.db: Invalid argument

$ db_dump -V
Berkeley DB 4.7.25: (May 15, 2008)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149525/query-firefox-password-database/149537#149537

Comment: Aha! The whole Berkeley DB thing was a red herring. Rather than closing this question, I'll leave it here with the reference to the real answer. Thanks, @IporSircer.